# How to modify manage_user_page.php in Mantis

Tags: php, mantis

I would like to show a new column for each user in the page : manage_user_page.php .

I have a new column called Org in my DB for the table 'mantis_user_table' and I would like to show it in manage_user_page.php view.

Do you know how can I do it without touching the source code? Is there any way with a plugin and a certain event or with a function?

thanks,

sara

My request is mostly if there is a working around without touching the source code. So if I can develop a plugin or any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mantis Event System to develop a plugin to show the fields on the User page. Please refer to https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Developers_Guide/html/dev.eventref.manage.user.html

Comment: Yes, it's true. But I don't see any event relating to manage_user_page.php

Comment: EVENT_MANAGE_USER_PAGE (Execute)
        This event allows plugins to do processing or display information on the View User page. It is triggered immediately after the reset password segment. Any output here should be contained within its own container.
        
Parameters
            <Integer>: User ID

Comment: that page is the manage_user_edit_page. and not the manage_user_page...

Comment: Please read the documentation carefully. It specifically says: This event allows plugins to do processing or display information on the View User page.

Comment: Indeed but they are different pages : View user page - > manage_user_edit_page.php where you can find the reset link as the doc said but what I need it's to show a new data on manage_user_page.php where you have ALL the users.